# Overwriting existing pointer in hooked function

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char, hook

I have a small problem I can't seem to figure out. I have hooked a function which has a `char*` parameter, for the record, the hook is working. Inside my own function I want to change the char pointer parameter to my own.

```
int Foo(char *buffer, int length)
{
    //..
    std::string cString(buffer);

    // some changes are made to cString here

    length = cString.length();
    memcpy(buffer, cString.c_str(), length);
    //..
}
```

Now it does work if I keep the length of the new string equal or lesser to the old one. But if I try to make it bigger it won't work.

How can I do this? My guess whas to re-alloc the buffer variable with the new length before copying it, but I couldn't get it to work that way.

Comment: `Foo` would need to be passed a `char **` to allow you to allocate a new buffer and return its address to the calling function.

Comment: @RichardCritten I'm not sure, but its a hooked function and it uses an already existing signature, thus I can't change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simply not how C-style strings (`char*`) work. What you ask is impossible.

You should see C strings as a memory address to the first character. The person who is responsible for the size of the memory block starting at that address is your caller. You can't change the size of the memory there.

To give an example, let's say someone gives you the address to their house and asks you to fill it with 1000 chairs. This is impossible, 1000 chairs do not fit inside the house, and you can't put them into the neighbors' house. You can't make the house larger either, because that would mean the house would overlap with the neighbors' house.

What you **can** do is allocate new memory (build a new house at a new location), fill it with your larger data (fill the house with 1000 chairs), and return back the address of the new string (give back the address of the house). Remember to inform your caller that they're now responsible to destroy the house when they're done with it.

---

One way you can do this is by taking a pointer to a string:

```
void f(const char* str, char** out) {
    int len = strlen(str);
    char* new_str = malloc(strlen + 5 + 1);
    strcpy(new_str, str);
    strcat(new_str + len, "world");
    *out = new_str;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    const char str[] = "hello ";
    char* new_str;
    f(str, &new_str);
    printf("%s\n", new_str);
    free(new_str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And how would I do that? Copy the source string into a bigger string (source length + added characters) and get the pointer of that?

Comment: @TheDutchMan I added an example.

Comment: I tried using malloc for that before, but it wouldn't allow me. That what made me ended up posting here. It tells me "void *" cannot be used to initialize and entity of the type "char *".

Comment: @TheDutchMan Compile your file as C, not as C++. Make sure you're using `gcc` instead of `g++` and your filename ends in `.c`.